# JavaScript: sort array of objects with Ukrainian letters

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
var countries = [
    {'id': 35, 'name': 'Перу'},
    {'id': 45, 'name': 'Індія'},
    {'id': 55, 'name': 'Єгипет'},
    {'id': 65, 'name': 'Албанія'},
]
```

I need to sort it by `name`. Here is my algorithm:

```
function mySort(s1, s2) {
    return s1.name.toString().localeCompare(s2.name.toString());
}

var sorted = countries.sort(mySort);

// result (incorrect)
sorted = [
    {'id': 55, 'name': 'Єгипет'},
    {'id': 45, 'name': 'Індія'},
    {'id': 65, 'name': 'Албанія'},
    {'id': 35, 'name': 'Перу'},
]

// must be
sorted = [
    {'id': 65, 'name': 'Албанія'},
    {'id': 55, 'name': 'Єгипет'},
    {'id': 45, 'name': 'Індія'},
    {'id': 35, 'name': 'Перу'},
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTpAh/) and screenshot of my result in jsfiddle.

[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've found that only Google chrome sorts incorrect: FireFox and Opera do it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working as you expected for me.

It doesn't make a functional difference, but you don't need to call `.toString()` on something that is already a String.  I.E., you can simplify `mySort` to this:

```
var mySort = function(s1, s2){
    return s1.name.localeCompare(s2.name);
}
```

(I also prefer to declare all functions as variables, as they're all the same in JavaScript - so they should be handled consistently.)

However, as to answer why this may not be working for you, per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/62b7ahzy%28v=vs.94%29.aspx (interestingly, [MDN's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) doesn't say anything about this) - emphasis mine:

> The localeCompare performs a locale-sensitive string comparison of the
>   stringVar and the stringExp and returns -1, 0, or +1, **depending on the
>   sort order of the system default locale**.

If you want something that will sort purely on the character codes without regards to the user's locale, you could use this instead:

```
var mySort = function(s1, s2){
    if(s1 == s2){
      return 0;
    }
    return s1.name > s2.name;
}
```

This will sort consistently, regardless of the client's or user's settings / preferences - but it also returns the results you classified as incorrect.

---

**Edit**:  As you mentioned that the behavior you're observing is specific to Google Chrome, this appears to be a known issue in Chrome, and is being tracked at http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459.

Comment: The same (incorrect) result for me... I'm using chrome console and my computers system language is Ukrainian. Maybe this is the reason...

Comment: I've updated my question with jsfiddle code and resulting screenshot

Comment: @VitaliPonomar - Please see the update to the bottom of my answer. This appears to be a known issue in Google Chrome, as shown in the linked bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sorted = countries.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) });
```

Comment: The same (incorrect) result for me... I'm using chrome console and my computers system language is Ukrainian. Maybe this is the reason...

Comment: What does this answer do that should affect the results in any way?

Comment: I've updated my question with jsfiddle code and resulting screenshot

Comment: I tested this using you countries object and it sorted correctly. It is surprising this does not work with your system language.